# order database query results based on capture date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have three models; User, upvote and piece.

A piece has many upvotes through the upvote model and those upvotes are given to pieces by the users.

Currently I rank the most highly voted pieces on a leaderboard:

```
@pieces = Piece.unscoped.order("votes DESC").first(5)
```

I also display details of the users who have voted for the particular piece, primarily the avatar.

I am trying to find a way to display the user information in the order in which they voted. E.g. the user who voted first should be displayed top of the list and stop the users from being displayed in the default scope order defined by the model.

The controller code is shown below:

```
def leaderboard
  @title = "Leaderboards"
  @pieces = Piece.unscoped.order("votes DESC").first(5)
  @voters = []
  @pieces.each do |voters|
    @voters << voters.users
  end
end
```

Any help on this would be massively appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
def leaderboard
  @title = "Leaderboards"
  @pieces = Piece.unscoped.order("votes DESC").first(5)
  @voters = []
  @pieces.each do |piece|
    piece.users.each do |user|
      @voters << user
    end
  end
end
```